# Custom Framework Element resize to fit parent

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am attempting to make a custom Framework Element object. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to have it resize to fit to the parent (such as a Border would do for example).

I have the constructor set up as below but the SizeChanged event is not called (except at the very beginning).

```
public MyFrameworkElement()
{
    this.SizeChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        this.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        this.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    };
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? unless you have something non-standard going on there is no reason to incur in non-standard practices. Please clarify

Comment: My class is empty. My draw method simply draws a black rectangle for reference. I'm not trying to do anything at the moment, just trying to get the simplest parts working first.

Comment: If you need a rectangle, just do `<Rectangle/>` in XAML. WPF is not winforms. Again, unless you need something `very` non-standard, there's no reason to incur in non-standard practices. WPF is about XAML and DataBinding, not procedural code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually you have to do such code in `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`.

example for MeasureOverride

```cs
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    //return the available size to use the container size
    return availableSize;
}
```

optionally you may choose to derive your element from `UserControl` or other suitable container to get this done for you.

more info on measure and arrange here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride

if you want to use your existing code, this should do, but not recommended

```cs
    protected override void OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
    {
        base.OnVisualParentChanged(oldParent);
        if (oldParent != null)
            (oldParent as FrameworkElement).SizeChanged -= Parent_SizeChanged;
        if (Parent != null)
            (Parent as FrameworkElement).SizeChanged += Parent_SizeChanged;
    }

    void Parent_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        this.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
    }
```

Comment: I tried setting the base class to UserControl but that didn't change anything. Why is the latter a bad idea?

Comment: by default `UserControl` take up all the available space, if it is not the case for you then could you post a working sample app which can reproduce the same? Secondly the approach is not a bad idea but when you have a strong layout framework from WPF doing all this, it becomes redundant so not recommended.